# Get data for month wise in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, angular2-services

I want to get data to each month. in my table data is stored like this:-

```
   "patient" : [ 
    {
        "status" : 'arrived',
         start_time: '2017-08-17T09:17:00.000Z

    }, 
    {
        "status" : 'arraived',
         start_time: '2017-08-16T07:17:00.000Z
    }, 
   {
        "status" : 'arrived',
         start_time: '2017-07-12T09:17:00.000Z

    }, 
    {
        "status" : 'arraived',
         start_time: '2017-07-05T08:10:00.000Z
    },
    {
        "status" : 'arrived',
         start_time: '2017-06-02T09:17:00.000Z

    }, 
    {
        "status" : 'arraived',
         start_time: '2017-05-05T08:16:00.000Z
    }
    ]
```

etc, 
and I want to sum of patient of each month (jan to des), like  this :-

```
    {
      "month" : 8,
      "count" : 2
   }and like this month 1 to 12
```

Comment: did you try using $group aggregation?

Comment: @ManojShevate   Yes I tried, but in this type I am able to count full year data, like if we take above example using $group aggregation code its showing count 6. But I want( 6 month count 1) , (7 month count 2) and (8 month count 2 )etc

Answer (score 2):

I assume, `patient` array is associated with a customer and the date is stored in mongo ISO format.

So, the actual document would look like :

```
{
    name: "stackOverflow",
    "patient" : [ 
    {
        "status" : 'arrived',
         "start_time": ISODate("2017-08-17T09:17:00.000Z")

    }, 
    {
        "status" : 'arraived',
         "start_time": ISODate("2017-08-16T07:17:00.000Z")
    }, 
   {
        "status" : 'arrived',
         "start_time": ISODate("2017-07-12T09:17:00.000Z")

    }, 
    {
        "status" : 'arraived',
         "start_time": ISODate("2017-07-05T08:10:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        "status" : 'arrived',
         "start_time": ISODate("2017-06-02T09:17:00.000Z")

    }, 
    {
        "status" : 'arraived',
         "start_time": ISODate("2017-05-05T08:16:00.000Z")
    }
    ]
}
```

here is a sample query which you can try -

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$patient"},
{ $group: {
    _id: {name: "$name", month: {$month: "$patient.start_time"}},
    count: { $sum: 1}
}},
{$group: {
    _id: "$_id.name",
    patient: {$push: {month: "$_id.month", count: "$count"}}
}}
])
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "_id" : "stackOverflow",
    "patient" : [
        {
            "month" : 5,
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "month" : 6,
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "month" : 7,
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "month" : 8,
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

You can change query according to your use-case. hope this will help you!

Comment: I have error please see my code where i am wrong in below section

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:-

```
  db.appointments.aggregate( [
   {
     $project: 
     {
       "patient_id": 1,
       "start_time": 1,
        "status": 1
     }
    },
            {
            $match: {
                'start_time' : { $gte: startdate.toISOString() },

                'status': { $eq: 'arrived' }
            } ,

            },
            { $group: {
                _id: {id: "$_id", start_time: {$month: "$appointments.start_time"}},
                count: { $sum: 1}
            }}
            ])
```

When I used this :-

```
   { $group: {
        _id: {id: "$_id", start_time: {$month: "$start_time"}},
        count: { $sum: 1}
        }
    }
```

its showing error message:-
     {"name":"MongoError","message":"can't convert from BSON type missing to Date","ok":0,"errmsg":"can't convert from BSON type missing to Date","code":16006,"codeName":"Location16006"}

And when I comment this its showing  this :-

Out Put here:-

```
   :[{"count":{"_id":"595b6f95ab43ec1f6c92b898","patient_id":"595649904dbe9525c0e036ef","start_time":"2017-07-04T10:35:00.000Z","status":"arrived"}},
```

{"count":{"_id":"595dff870960d425d4f14633","patient_id":"5956478b4dbe9525c0e036ea","start_time":"2017-03-08T09:14:00.000Z","status":"arrived"}},{"count":{"_id":"595dffaa0960d425d4f14634","patient_id":"595649904dbe9525c0e036ef","start_time":"2017-03-17T09:15:00.000Z","status":"arrived"}},{"count":{"_id":"595dffcf0960d425d4f14635","patient_id":"595648394dbe9525c0e036ec","start_time":"2017-06-08T09:15:00.000Z","status":"arrived"}},{"count":{"_id":"595dfffb0960d425d4f14636","patient_id":"5956478b4dbe9525c0e036ea","start_time":"2017-06-20T09:16:00.000Z","status":"arrived"}},{"count":{"_id":"595e00160960d425d4f14637","patient_id":"5959ea7f80388b19e0b57817","start_time":"2017-08-17T09:17:00.000Z","status":"arrived"}}]}

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access `$appointments` in grouping stage and it's not been projected in in first step

Answer (score 0):

```
const group = {
  $group: {
    _id: { month: { $month: "$createdAt" } },
    count: { $sum: 1 },
  },
};

const groups = {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    patient: { $push: { month: '$_id.month', count: '$count' } },
  },
};

return db.Patient.aggregate([group, groups]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. It will make you answer of higher quality and is more likely to attract upvotes.